# pyplot.scatter erase data and axe not great

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

He everyone!

I'm making a simple 2d graph with data.
[image]

**Errors**

- I've a csv file which I extract data and when I show the plot everything is ok.
  But if I add a .scatter it's just showing the one I added. (like you've found a new thing and you want to compare it to your database by adding it to the graph)
- The y-axis is not in an ascending order..

My Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


def faireGraph(fichierCsv):
    with open(fichierCsv) as fichierCsv:
        ligneFin = [ligne.rstrip().rsplit(',') for ligne in fichierCsv.readlines()]

        xLabel = ligneFin[0][0]
        yLabel = ligneFin[0][1]

        xCoord = []
        for i in range(1, len(ligneFin)):
            xCoord.append((float(ligneFin[i][0]), i))
        xCoord.sort(key = lambda x:x[0])

        yCoord = [ligne[1] for ligne in ligneFin[1:]]

        toutesEspeces = []
        for j in range(1, len(ligneFin)):
            toutesEspeces.append(ligneFin[xCoord[j - 1][1]][2])






        for i in range(len(xCoord)):
            if toutesEspeces[i] == 'setosa':
                plt.scatter(xCoord[i][0], yCoord[xCoord[i][1] - 1], c='blue')
            if toutesEspeces[i] == 'versicolor':
                plt.scatter(xCoord[i][0], yCoord[xCoord[i][1] - 1], c='red')
            if toutesEspeces[i] == 'virginica':
                plt.scatter(xCoord[i][0], yCoord[xCoord[i][1] - 1], c='green')

        choixAjtValeur = input("Voulez vous ajouter une valeur à votre tableau ? oui ou non ? (o/n): ")




        rougeLegend = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='versicolor')
        bleuLegend = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='setosa')
        vertLegend = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='virginica')

        if choixAjtValeur == "o":
            ajtCoodX = float(input("Coordonée x: "))
            ajtCoodY = float(input("Coordonée y: "))

            plt.scatter(ajtCoodX, ajtCoodY, color = "black")

            inconnuLegend = mpatches.Patch(color='black', label='inconnu')

            plt.legend(handles=[vertLegend, rougeLegend, bleuLegend, inconnuLegend])

        else:
            plt.legend(handles=[vertLegend, rougeLegend, bleuLegend])

        plt.xlabel(xLabel)
        plt.ylabel(yLabel)




        print("Affichage du graphique en cours...")

        plt.show()


oui = "iris_2D.csv"

faireGraph(oui)
```

Any help would be precious thanks!

Comment: The plot looks pretty good doesn't it? I would also recommend using Numpy or Pandas to read the CSV file rather than reading them into native python Lists.

Comment: @tiega look at the y-axis values :/. Thanks, I'll check that !

Comment: Sorry! I see now. It seems that because you are using string parsing to split the data (.rsplit(".")), the values are actually stored in the Python lists as Strings rather than numeric valules. You can call "float(value)" on each of the values to convert them from strings to numeric values, which Matplotlib will plot correctly. For that purpose, you can use Pandas and run `dataframe = pd.read_csv("CSV_FILE_NAME")` to directly load the numeric data into a dataframe.

Comment: @tiega that solved the whole thing !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because you are using string parsing to split the data (.rsplit(".")), the values are actually stored in the Python lists as Strings rather than numeric valules. You can call "float(value)" on each of the values to convert them from strings to numeric values, which Matplotlib will plot correctly.